# Delay Colorbox to start during another animation

Tags: jquery, colorbox, delay

I'm trying to delay colorbox from opening, but if a delay is present it doesn't run at all. I've tried so many things, but I'm stuck. Anyone know how I can get colorbox to pause while the first animation runs? It's 6000ms, but I'd like colorbox to start at 3000ms.

Thanks!

This works:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
   $('a[data-test]').click(function(){
   var anim = $(this).attr('data-test');
   buttonAnim(anim);
   $.colorbox({href:"contact/index.html"});
;})
```

This works, but with 0ms delay:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
   $('a[data-test]').click(function(){
   var anim = $(this).attr('data-test');
   buttonAnim(anim);
   $('a[data-test]').delay(3000).colorbox({href:"contact/index.html"});
;})
```

Answer (score 0):

hmm i don't know the plugin of the colorbox but maybe you can use some tricks like:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $('a[data-test]').click(function(){
   var anim = $(this).attr('data-test');
   buttonAnim(anim);
   $("#divOfYourChoice").animate( {'height': $("#divOfYourChoice").height()},3000,
   function($('a[data-test]').colorbox({href:"contact/index.html"});)
   );
;})
```

Where divOfYourChoice is how it's name says any div on the page. Of course this isn't the most elegant solution but it should work anyway. Hope this helps you to solve your problem (until you find a better solution)

optionally you could use the setTimeout like:

```
 setTimeout(function($('a[data-test]').colorbox({href:"contact/index.html"});),3000);
```